# What is the best workaround for supporting all existing DATEs?

Tags: date-time

I want to make a weblog that has with every date 1 or more weblog posts, e.g.:

**Januari 24 Year 41 : Roman Emperor Caligula was murdered by Cassius Chaerea and the disgruntled Praetorian Guards. Caligula's uncle Claudius was proclaimed emperor in his place.**

or

**Januari 1 Year 153 BC : Roman consuls begin their year in office.**

or

**Februari 1 Year 2038 : Humans survived**

What would be the best way to do this in WordPress if I want to support URL hacking?

p.s. custom fields + custom posts + custom taxonomy was the first thing I thought of but maybe there are better alternatives relying on the current date system.

related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Representing_the_number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix time is defined as the amount of seconds since the "Unix epoch," which is 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970.

It works both forwards and backwards -- so technically you shouldn't have trouble representing dates all the way back to Jan. 1, year 1, but the numbers would be negative and extremely large.

EDIT: PHP appears not to be able to handle those dates easily, at least according to one basic test. Both `echo $time = strtotime("January 1, 1");` and `echo $time = strtotime("January 1, 0001");` result in `978325200`.

I think the best option is, as you muse, categories. Whether or not you want to deal with custom categories might be a matter of preference, but I suspect normal categories with the names you lay out would work just fine.

Comment: well I do because WordPress will not let me enter these years!

Comment: it only ACCEPTS dates after  Jan 01, 100 (before that the editor becomes red) BUT... when you click "update" strange things happen. The admin screen shows suddenly the current date, the edit thing shows suddenly Jan 1, 1970 and the post altogether is not on any of these permalinks if you have the date or time in the permalink :) (which may or may not be a bug)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about WordPress specifics on processing date when saving post, but it stores post's date in database under `datetime` type, which according to [MySQL The DATETIME, DATE, and TIMESTAMP Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) only has range of **1000-01-01 00:00:00 to 9999-12-31 23:59:59** and so won't go back as far as you want.

So it is definitely better to store date separately (custom field makes sense) as string or timestamp.

Also [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is usually awesome, but has limitations of its own:

> The valid range of a timestamp is
>   typically from **Fri, 13 Dec 1901
>   20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038
>   03:14:07 UTC**. (These are the dates
>   that correspond to the minimum and
>   maximum values for a 32-bit signed
>   integer.) Additionally, not all
>   platforms support negative timestamps,
>   therefore your date range may be
>   limited to no earlier than the Unix
>   epoch. This means that e.g. dates
>   prior to Jan 1, 1970 will not work on
>   Windows, some Linux distributions, and
>   a few other operating systems. PHP
>   5.1.0 and newer versions overcome this limitation though.

Overall I suspect that for such extreme dates you will need to write your own code or find some ready-made by third party.

Comment: i think i get it: as soon as the *nix world decides to migrate to 64 bit signed as standard all custom coding I have done will be for nothing... :( unless.. i find a 64 bit signed os support + have support for that inside wordpress build as a change request? ah.. no wait... my custom field SHOULD store a 64 bit signed integer so whenever the unix/windows/linux world decides that 2038 is becoming scary and standardizes on 64 bit signed integer that i can then migrate simply to the new system and only have that intermediate in a custom field i think.